# How to move to a particular tab present in a aspx page using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabcontrol

am using  vantage.aspx page in my asp.net application, which contains tabpanels like "tabpnlvantage", "tabpnlCell","tabpnlGrid". I have a link button in my "Home.aspx" page, if i select a particular link button in "home.aspx" page it should navigate to the "tabpnlvantage" tab in the "vantage.aspx page". how should i do this, can any one help me out. thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @catherin are you using the tabcontrol in the ajax control tool kit?

Comment: @cathering: you should add the TabIndex to the URL-parameter f.e. `monitoring.aspx?Tab=2`. Then you can set the TabContainer's `ActiveTabIndex` to it in monitoring.aspx.

Answer (score 3):

Use QueryString. In Home.aspx:

```
<a href='vantage.aspx?tab=tabpnlvantage' />
```

In vantage.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(! IsPostBack) {
      var tab = Request.QueryString["tab"];
      if(! string.IsNullOrEmpty(tab)) {
         foreach(TabPanel t in TabContainer.Tab) {
             if(t.ID == tab)
             {
                 TabContainer.ActiveTab = t;
                 break;
             }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: error is throwing like,"TabContainer does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Of course, in place of TabContainer you should put the name of your TabContainer

Comment: hi..can some one help me out from this problem. am still stuck with the same issue.

Comment: moving to a particular tab in another page.

Comment: can u plz tel me any other way for this problem?

Comment: <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn1" runat="server" 
                                                PostBackUrl="~/webpages/vantage.aspx?tab=tabpnlCell" Font-Size="Small" ></asp:LinkButton>

Comment: if i click this link button in home page, it should direct me to the  tab named 'tabpncell' in my vantage.aspx page

Comment: Ok, can you update your question above, with the code in vantage.aspx and in vantege.aspx.cs?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure it works like that. When you click on the required 'tab', the associated content should be displayed.

Comment: no.. iam just using an asp tab panel inside a asp tab container

Answer (score 0):

Use `TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex = 2;`

tab index starts from 0.

```
<ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0">  
                <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="tabpnlvantage" HeaderText="Header1" runat="server">  
                    <ContentTemplate>  
                    &nbsp;
                    </ContentTemplate>  
                </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>  
                <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="tabpnlcells" HeaderText="Header2" runat="server" >  
                    <ContentTemplate>  

                    </ContentTemplate>              
                </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>  
                <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="tabpnlgrid" HeaderText="Header3" runat="server">  
                    <ContentTemplate>  

                    </ContentTemplate>              
                </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>  
            </ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
```